# How to Access different methods in Web API from console Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-web-api

How do i acces my methods in my webapi when there are multiple get,post and delete methods from my console application, how do i differentiate them this is my api controller

```
            public IQueryable<Store> GetAll()
    {                     
        return StoreRepository.All;
    }
    //GetAll Stores including all relation tables
    public IQueryable<Store> GetAllIncluding()
    {                   
        return StoreRepository.AllIncluding();
    }

    //Get store by id/id=5
    public Store Find(long storeid)
    {
        stores = StoreRepository.Find(storeid);
        return stores;
    }

    //Insert or Update Store
    public void InsertorUpdateWithGraph(Store store)
    {
        StoreRepository.InsertOrUpdateWithGraph(store);
    }

    //Insert or Update StoreDetail
    public void InsertOrUpdateStoreDetail(StoreDetail storedetail)
    {
        StoreRepository.InsertOrUpdateStoreDetail(storedetail);
    }

    //Get StoreDetail by id/id=5
    public StoreDetail FindStoreDetail(long storedetailid)
    {
        storedetail = StoreRepository.FindStoreDetail(storedetailid);
        return storedetail;
    }

     public List<StoreDetail> GetAllStoreDetails(long storedetailid)
    {
        List<StoreDetail> storedetails = StoreRepository.GetAllStoreDetails(storedetailid);
        return storedetails;
    }
      public Sage FindSage(long sageid)
    {
        return StoreRepository.FindSage(sageid);
    }
```

like this i may have more than two get,post,insert or update methods i have to acces this methods from my console application how can i map the methods i want,cana any one help me here how will i define the routes for this

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple "Get..." actions and you can get away without `HttpGet` attribute because they start with "Get". "Find..." methods need to be decorated with `HttpGet`
Those "Insert..." you need to decorate with `HttpPost` or `HttpPut` attributes.
Parameters to these methods can be configured in two ways. You can POST object like `{id:"ddd",name:"nnn"}` to action like

```
MyAction(int id, string name)
```

Web APi framework threats any methods that start with Post..., Delete..., Get..., Put... as corresponding Http Verbs. But you can name them the way you with and then decorate with Http attributes.

When it comes to parameters, it is about a correlation of your controller actions to the routes.

And now, to run it from the console application you can use `HttpClient`

```
     string _webSiteUrl = "www.ffsdfds.com"
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_webSiteUrl);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); // for posting
     HttpResponseMessage resp = httpClient.GetAsync("/api/area/getall").Result;
```